# What is the easiest and most secure way to secure HTTP API calls on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, security, http, rest

I want to develop apps for Android, iOS and have a web interface as well, I want the mobile apps to communicate with the server, which is the best way I can make this secure? I would like to use something that works well with both Android and iOS and it is easy to implement server side.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) on your server. Covers all of your requirements. Besides, any non-SSL HTTP communication is insecure by default.

Comment: Just one more thing, if you would use SSL you should get normal (not self-signed) SSL serticiface. Android default http client doesn't accept self-signed SSL sertificates.